# Consequences/Corollaries/Theorems due to Burnside lemma?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I don't quite understand why Burnside's lemma
$$
|X/G|=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |X_g|
$$
should be called a "lemma". By "lemma", we should mean there is something coming after it, presumably a theorem. However, I could not find a theorem which requires Burnside as a lemma. In every book I read, the author jumps into calculations using Burnside rather than further theorems.

Question: What are some important consequences of Burnside Lemma, and why is it called a "lemma"?

Comment: Not only is it not a lemma, it is also [not due to Burnside](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose G acts on H where $|G|,|H|<\infty$.  For each $g\in G$, consider the permutation character associated with the action.  That is, $\chi(g)=|\{\alpha\in H:\alpha\cdot g=\alpha\}|$.
Then, $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=\sum_{\alpha\in H}|G_{\alpha}|=n|G|$, where n is the number of orbits of G on H (the result of Burside's Lemma).

Also, we have the Fundamental Counting Principle: if $O_{\alpha}$ is the orbit of $\alpha$, then $|O_{\alpha}|=|G:G_{\alpha}|$, and since G is finite, $|O_{\alpha}|$ divides $|G|$.  Then, as Chris stated, from here we get the class equation.

The number of orbits pops up all over Group Theory, so don't think of Burside's Lemma as a lemma that should have a theorem immediately following, but rather a "tool" that we can refer to very frequently for many theorems.

Answer (score 0):

One consequence is for the necklace problem, see this post:

[Necklace problem with Burnside's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016732/necklace-problem-with-burnsides-lemma)

Comment: I'm confused. The answer to the necklace problem seems to be $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ from a basic calculation.  Is the Burnside lemma used to turn an easy calculation into a hard calculation?

Comment: If you want to answer necklace problems for a generic number of beads (not just a few), you will need Burnside lemma. See for example Proposition 4.1 in this paper:
http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/papers_html/par.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An closely related fact,  by looking at the *class equation*, is that a nontrivial $p$-group has nontrivial center.