# Using burnside's lemma to calculate a smaller subset of unique, color-agnostic bracelets

Tags: group-theory, necklace-and-bracelets

We have a child's toy, which is a ball made of 12 colored wedges (3 Red, 3 Green, 3 Blue, 3 Yellow).  Our child asked the sensible question 'how many different patterns are possible?'.

In researching the answer, I discovered it's a mathematically complex and interesting question!  My math level is advanced high school/entry level university - sufficient to determine that Burnside's lemma is the right tool and to more or less understand its application to this problem.  This is essentially a 'bracelet' problem, as I understand it.  But I would like to solve not for the total unique bracelets, but for a smaller subset of unique arrangements that are color agnostic (I'll define this here as 'unique patterns', lacking a more accurate term).  E.g. -RRY-GGG-BBB-YRY- is considered the same arrangement as -GGB-RRR-YYY-BGB-.  The pattern is the same even though the colors are switched.

From my research, my starting point was a similar related problem asked at the link below and answered very helpfully by Marko Riedel:

[Necklace problem with Burnside's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016732/necklace-problem-with-burnsides-lemma)

As Marko showed using Burnside's lemma, the total arrangements of that 6 bead 'bracelet' (or a simpler toy of 6 wedges of three colors) would be 11.  But the smaller subset of 'unique patterns' which are color agnostic are 5.  It was easy enough to identify those 5 manually, but what I am interested in is how Burnside's lemma could be correctly applied to find the unique (color agnostic) patterns possible on this more complex toy of 12 wedges in 4 colors.

My starting point was to calculate the higher amount of all possible 'bracelets'.  The identity gives $12! /( 3!^4) = 369{,}600$.  And unless I'm mistaken, the reflection symmetries yield no candidates and the only rotation symmetries which do are by 4 and 8 spaces (giving 24 each).  This gives:

(369,600 + 24 + 24) / 24 = 15,402 possible bracelets.

This gives me an upper limit, but how would I then reduce this to the subset of 'unique patterns' which are agnostic as to color placement, as it's not feasible to calculate this manually.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated by this math curious family!

(note: resubmitted with additional context as requested by moderator to my first question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following  presents some commentary  and some ideas. What  we have
here is another instance of  **Power Group Enumeration** as defined by
Harary and Palmer in *Graphical  Enumeration* and also by Fripertinger
in *Enumeration in  Musical Theory.* The scenario is  always the same,
we  have a  row of  slots with  a group  permuting them  and a  set of
objects  going into  these slots,  with a  second group  permuting the
objects.  We then  use Burnside, indeed the  Polya Enumeration Theorem
and Power Group Enumeration are both applications of this lemma.  Here
the question  is how we  can assign objects  (colors) to the  slots so
they remain  fixed under  a given slot  permutation.  (We  count these
assignments and  average over the  number of slot  permutations.) With
colors only, they  must be constant on the cycles  of the permutation,
which is  basic Burnside.  With  weighted objects, they must  still be
constant, but each admissible assignment to  a cycle of some order $q$
contributes $q$ copies of each object to the generating function. This
is PET. Finally,  with a group acting  on the objects as  well for the
assignment to be  fixed we must count  the ways in which  we may cover
the  cycles  of the  slot  permutation  with  cycles from  the  object
permutation  by opening  the  cycle from  the  object permutation  and
placing consecutive complete  copies of it on the cycle  from the slot
permutation.  In this way when the slot / object permutation pair acts
on  the assignment  it merely  rotates on  the cycle,  being fixed  as
required  by Burnside.   This  is PGE.  One example  of  many that  is
possible treats edge  colorings of the cube with  swappable colors and
can     be      found     at      the     following      [MSE     link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/)
.    Here   is   an
excerpt  of the  generating function  that  we obtain  for coloring  a
bracelet of twelve slots with at most four colors:

$${P_{{1}}}^{12}+35\,{P_{{1}}}^{6}{P_{{2}}}^{6}+38
\,{P_{{1}}}^{5}{P_{{2}}}^{7}+29\,{P_{{1}}}^{4}{P
_{{2}}}^{8}+297\,{P_{{1}}}^{4}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{
3}}}^{4}\\+12\,{P_{{1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{9}+1170\,{P
_{{1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{5}+424\,{P_{{
1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{6}+713\,{P_{{1}}
}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{3}{P_{{4}}}^{3}\\+6\,
{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{10}+386\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P
_{{2}}}^{5}{P_{{3}}}^{5}+610\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{
2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{6}\\+340\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}
}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{7}+5890\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^
{3}{P_{{3}}}^{3}{P_{{4}}}^{4}+\ldots$$

Therefore the answer for three instances each of four colors is
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{713.}$$

The Maple code for the above  is quite compact and straightforward and
follows below.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d;

    add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n))/n;
end;

pet_cycleind_dihedral :=
proc(n)
local s;

    s := 1/2*pet_cycleind_cyclic(n);

    if(type(n, odd)) then
        s := s + 1/2*a[1]*a[2]^((n-1)/2);
    else
        s := s + 1/4*(a[1]^2*a[2]^((n-2)/2) + a[2]^(n/2));
    fi;

    s;
end;


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_indets2rep :=
proc(ip)
local rep, var, deg, pos, s;

    rep := []; pos := 1;

    for var in indets(ip) do
        for deg to degree(ip, var) do
            rep :=
            [op(rep), [seq(s, s=pos..pos+op(1, var)-1)]];
            pos := pos + op(1, var);
        od;
    od;

    rep;
end;

bracelet_colorings_gf :=
proc(B, C)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cols, rep, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, len_a, len_b, p, q,
    parts, alldeg, cols, col, v;

    if C = 1 then return P[1]^B fi;
    if B = 1 then return P[1] fi;

    idx_slots := pet_cycleind_dihedral(B);
    idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(C);

    res := 0;

    for term_b in idx_cols do
        rep := pet_indets2rep(term_b);

        for term_a in idx_slots do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in rep do
                    len_b := nops(v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*
                        mul(P[col], col in v_b)
                        ^(len_a/len_b);
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    parts := 0;

    for cols in expand(res) do
        alldeg :=
        sort(map(v -> degree(cols, v),
                 [op(indets(cols))]));

        parts := parts +
        lcoeff(cols)*
        mul(P[v]^alldeg[v], v=1..nops(alldeg));
    od;

    parts;
end;
```

As a bonus  we can count the colorings of  a twelve-bracelet with some
number of  swappable colors  (at most  twelve) which  is a  great deal
simpler and  faster than  working with  generating functions.  This is
shown below.

```
bracelet_pg :=
proc(B, C)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_colors, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if B = 1 or C = 1 then return 1 fi;

    idx_slots := pet_cycleind_dihedral(B);
    idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(C);

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_colors do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

This gives the sequence

$$1, 122, 3960, 30108, 88508, 144587, 171283, 178190, 179204,\\
179300, 179306, 179307, 179307,\ldots$$

In  particular  with  at  most  four colors  we  find  $30108$  unique
colorings. We obtain for an exact number of colors the sequence

$$1, 121, 3838, 26148, 58400, 56079, 26696, \\ 
6907, 1014, 96, 6, 1, 0, \ldots$$

We get for exactly four colors that there are $26148$ unique colorings.
Note how the colorings with eleven colors can be counted by inspection
(place two markers on a twelve-bracelet).

Observe that the data for an exact number of colors are to be found at
[OEIS A152176](https://oeis.org/A152176) where a considerable variety
of additional material awaits.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful Marko.  Thank you very much for responding.  Do I understand correctly that this shows there are 30,108 unique colorings of the bracelet using 4x3 colors, and that there are 713 'unique' patterns, where the colors can be switched and the pattern the same?

Comment: Thanks! There are $30108$ patterns using at most four colors under the dihedral symmetry of the twelve-bracelet and $713$ patters under the same symmetry consisting of three instances each of four different colors. (The first counts all partitions into at most four colors i.e. it includes two colors as shown in the GF.)